# jQuery's .prepend is replacing my content instead of adding it to the beginning

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to place the text from an input in a list, and allow the user to add multiple items, with the new items being added to the top. I'm using .prepend, which should add the new item to the top, but instead it is replacing the existing element. Any thoughts?

[It's on Codepen](http://codepen.io/brooksroche/pen/EClmD)

```
function getParameter(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
        results = regex.exec(location.search);
    return results === null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
function postMessage(){
    var currentTime = new Date().getSeconds(),
        thoughts = getParameter("post"),
        message = "<li>" + thoughts + " - " + currentTime + "</li>";
    $("#list").prepend(message);
}
$("form").on( "submit", postMessage());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That happens because when a form is submitted, the page is reloaded. So your content isn't really being replaced, what in fact happens is (1) the page reloads clearing all content, and (2) the input which has been added to the URL as parameter, is now prepended to the list as first and only content.

To prevent this, you can either:

1. Prevent the forms's default behaviour by changing
   `$("form").on("submit", postMessage());` to
   `$("form").on("submit", function(e){e.preventDefault(); postMessage();});`.
2. Change the `<input type="submit" />` to `<input type="button" />` (a regular button), bypassing the whole submit issue altogether. Since the form doesn't need to be submitted, the submit-button really isn't necessary, and even a bit misplaced. You also don't need to prevent any default behaviour, which is a lot cleaner in my opinion.
   **This option has my preference, so I'll explain this option in more detail below:**

---

```js
$(window).on("load", function(){
  $(".input").click(function() {
    $(this).select();
  });
  
  $("#search .submit").click(function(){
    var currentTime = new Date().getSeconds(),
        thoughts = $("#search .input").val(),
        message = "<li>" + thoughts + " - " + currentTime + " seconds </li>";
    $("#list").prepend(message);  
  });
});
```

```css
html{
  height: 100%;
}
body{
  background: #fff;
  font-size: 13px;
  min-width: 800px;
}
br{
  clear: left;
}

#header{
  background:cornflowerblue;
  padding: 10px 5px;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px #fff;
  text-align:center;
}
#search{
  display: inline-block;
}
.input{
  width: 300px;
  padding: 2px 3px;
  border: 2px solid #A2C4DA;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  line-height:2;
}
.submit{
  padding: 6px 12px;
  vertical-align: top;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #fff;
  background:#fff;
  border: 1px solid #6FD6F7;
  line-height:2;
}
.submit:hover{cursor:pointer;}

#page{
  width: 800px;
  background: dodgerblue;
  border: 1px solid #ffffff;
  margin: 10px auto 0px;
  padding: 1em 2em;
  font-size:2em;
}
#page li{
  list-style:none;
  text-align:center;
  color: #fff;
  border-top:1px solid #fff;
}
#page li:nth-child(n+1){
  border:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="header">
  <div id="search">
    <form>
      <input type="text" class="input" placeholder="thoughts?" />
      <input type="button" class="submit" value="Post" />
    </form>
  </div>
  <br>
</div>

<div id="page">
  <ul id="list"></ul>
</div>
```

(**codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yefcw**)

- Because the page doesn't reload anymore, you can't use `thoughts = getParameter("post")` anymore. Since the page doesn't reload, no parameter is added to the URL.
  To get that working again, I changed that line to `thoughts = $("#post").val()`.
- I gave the `<input type="text"/>` and `<input type="button"/>` both classes, so they can be referenced by JS and CSS. I removed the `name` from the input-field, because it's not needed in this situation.
  *(I could have used ID's instead of classes, but the classes give you more flexibility. For instance, if you want a second input-form on the page just like this one, you can just copy-paste it, except the `<div id="search">` needs another ID. Then, in the JS you make another click-handler like `$("#search .submit").click(` where you also change the `#search` to the new ID.

  But in the CSS you have to change nothing, because the CSS rules for the classes `.input` and `.submit` will also style the new input field and button.)*
- I updated the CSS selectors accordingly to reference the new classes.
- I removed `method="get"` from your form, since it's not used or needed anymore.
- I removed the `getParameter()` function, since you don't need it anymore.
- I added the `$("#input").click(...` function, which selects all the text in the input field when you click on it. This is not necessary, but I thought it might be a little bit more user-friendly.
- I wrapped your code in `window.load`. This is just good practice to make sure the code isn't executed before the page is completely loaded.

Comment: @user2548213 - I optimized my answer a bit, changing the `<input type="submit"/>` to `<input type="button"/>`. A few other changes came with that. So if you're interested, have another look

Comment: Is window.load necessary when the function only runs when the button is clicked? I decided to clear the text input value on submit rather than selecting. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, clearing works just as fine, all a matter of choice. Is window.load necessary? Not absolutely in this case. But not because the code only runs when the button is clicked. It starts to matter when you for example have a lot of HQ images on your page, because they take a while to load. Say you have a function attached to a button click, that manipulates all the images in some way. Now, if you don't use *window.load* and some of those images are not fully loaded yet, that manipulation code will fail and cause errors, because the code can't find them, which will break your site...

Comment: In your case all elements are probably loaded before you even see them, and by the time the button is loaded, the input-field will be loaded as well. But that's a dangerous game to play, 'cause there's gonna come a time when you forget to use the *window.load* when you really should, and something isn't loaded yet, but you don't notice it during development because it doesn't always happen, and then your site is online and things start to break and you don't even know about it because visitors aren't gonna complain, they just stop visiting...

Comment: But eventually it's your choice, I didn't use it at first either, I didn't even want to use jQuery because I felt that whole library clouded up my clean code. Those are just things you have to learn and choose for yourself. And maybe there are even situations where *window.load* breaks the functionality of your site, although I can't come up with anything now..

Comment: **My advice**: read about it. On StackOverflow, w3schools, other JS learning sites. Don't take my word for it, take an hour or two to completely understand what *window.load* does, what *document.ready* does, what the difference is and what the pros and cons of both are. I'm not gonna tell you that it's OK to just remove it, hell it's one line, two if you count the closing brackets. But I'm also not gonna pretend I know best. It can't hurt in this situation, but if you really don't want it, in this situation you could probably also leave it out.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, the submit button is submitting the form which is causing the whole page to be reloaded/reset.  The reload of the page causes the `<ul>` to be reloaded without content and then you insert content.  This is repeated each time.  You might want to consider not using `<form>` processing for getting input data.

Answer (score 0):

```
function getParameter(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
        results = regex.exec(location.search);
    return results === null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
function postMessage(){
 var currentTime = new Date().getSeconds(),
  thoughts = $("#post").val(),
  message = "<li>" + thoughts + " - " + currentTime + " seconds </li>";
 $("#page").prepend(message);
  $("#post").val("");
}
$("form").on( "submit", function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  postMessage();
});
```

and put a id in inputtext box

```
<input type="text" name="post" id="post" placeholder="thoughts?"/>
```